# GGPLOT relative frequency histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot the relative frequency of 1D data from 3 clusters.  What I want is a single histogram that uses color to distinguish between the 3 clusters, and I want the height of each bin to represent the relative frequency of that value range for a particular cluster.

The code is as follows:

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(gtools)
library(ggplot2)

K       = 3                    # number of clusters
p_p     = c(0.25, 0.25, 0.5)   # population weights
theta_p = c(2, 5, 15)          # population gamma params - shape
phi_p   = c(2,2, 5)            # population gamma params - scale


N_p = c(25, 25, 50)            # sample size within each cluster
set.seed(1)                    # set seed so that the results are the same each time
y <- numeric()          
## We will now sample data from all three clusters
y[1:N_p[1]]                    <- rgamma(N_p[1], theta_p[1], phi_p[1])
y[(N_p[1]+1): (N_p[1]+N_p[2])] <- rgamma(N_p[2], theta_p[2], phi_p[2])
y[(N_p[1]+N_p[2]+1): sum(N_p)] <- rgamma(N_p[3], theta_p[3], phi_p[3])



Data = data.frame(y = y, source = as.factor(c(rep(1,25), rep(2,25), rep(3,50))))



ggplot(Data, aes(x=y, color = source))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)),fill="white", position="dodge", binwidth = 0.5) +
  theme(legend.position="top")+labs(title="Samples against Theoretical Dist",y="Frequency", x="Sample Value")

length(which(y[1:25]<=0.5))/length(y)
length(which(y[1:25]<=0.5))/length(y[0:25])
```

Now, what I want is for the first red histogram bar to have a height equal to length(which(y[1:25]<=0.5))/length(y[0:25]).  I would understand if i was getting length(which(y[1:25]<=0.5))/length(y) instead, and I could work around that.

However, I'm getting a height of around 0.12, which doesn't match either of these values and has me thinking I am completely misunderstanding ..count.. and sum(..count..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't with your understanding of `..count..` but in your assumption of how `binwidth` works. You have assumed that setting it to 0.5 will set the breaks at 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5 etc, but in fact it sets it at the lowest value of the range of your data. So in fact, the height of your first bar is `length(which(y[1:25] <= (min(y) + 0.5)))/length(y)`, which is 13.

You can specify `breaks` in `geom_histogram` to work round this limitation:

```r
ggplot(Data, aes(x = y, color = source)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = stat(count)/length(y)), fill = "white", 
                 position = "dodge", breaks = seq(0, 6, 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top" +
  labs(title = "Samples against Theoretical Dist",
       y = "Frequency", x = "Sample Value")
```

[image]

Now each bar is 1/100th of the count since the vector is 100 long.